# Как сделать так, чтобы при введении числа меньше 100 и больше 999 выводилось "False" (у меня выводится "Lock")

Tags: python-3.x

```
N = input("Введите пароль: ")
if N<str(100) or N>str(999):
    print("False")
else:
    if str(100)<N and N<str(999):
        if sum(map(int, str(N)))==13:
            print("Enter")
        else:
            print("Lock")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сравниваете строки. При сравнении строк, `"99"` больше, чем `"100"`.

```
N = int(input("Введите пароль: "))
if N < 100 or N > 999:
```

или

```
N = input("Введите пароль: ")
if len(N) != 3:
```